# How can we get info from a webpage on Android?

Tags: android, html

How can we get info from a webpage(link on it that downloads an excel file when you click on it)? What subjects should be searched in order to do that on Android? Thanks.

Comment: Consider using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) parse info in html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you will not able to know what are the link is for. There is a way to know about the link of the webview on which user clicks and it is [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

Here is a code using which you can know that the clicked link has XLS file or pdf file or others. You can also block the link using that code

```
public class TestingActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      WebView view = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
      view.setWebViewClient(new MwebViewClient());
    }

  class  MwebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains(".xls")) {
            Log.d("Blah", "This link contains XLS file");
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }   
    }
}
```